# How to prevent css elements from moving on window resize

Tags: html, css

I am using this simple line in css but the element moves on window resize. I want them to be fixed. what should I do:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Don't use percentages. Use fixed values.

Comment: the % will change when you resize the window, use px instead

Comment: but when i use px, elements will be in different places depending on screen resolution. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Pixel-base positioned elements will always be in the same place regardless of screen resolution.  If you give the element a top: 10px it will be at 10px whether the screen height is 500px or 1000px.  If you give the element top: 10%, it will be at 50px on a screen that is 500px in height or at 100px if the screen is 100px in height.

Comment: im using px and still elements move on screen re size.

Comment: To your comment "% are relative to parent or nearest anchestor", that's not entirely true.  Elements with position: fixed are always relative to the window.  They are not relative to the nearest positioned ancestor like an element that has position: absolute set.

Answer (score 0):

**% => depends on the size of the browser window**

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more info about positioning.

Comment: but when i use px, elements will be in different places depending on screen resolution. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: It's physically impossible to fix elements and expect them to be at the same place depending on the windows size. If you want your elements to be at the same place for any window size, then you want them to move

Comment: % are relative to parent or nearest anchestor. They are only relative to browser window if there is no such element.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Make a [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and explain a little bit more what you want, it's not clear.

Comment: im using px and still elements move on screen re size.